# Gulp вытаскиваем файл без папки

Tags: javascript, gulp, jade, pug

Есть таск, который преобразует pug в html, чтобы не прописывать путь до каждого файла, хочу сделать blocks/**/*.pug, то есть во всех директориях, с любым именем и расширением pug и положить получившиеся html файлы в директорию app.
Проблема в том, что такс в том виде, в котором он сейчас в директорию app складывает не одни получившиеся html файлы, а папки в которых находились pug файлы, вместе с hmtl получившимися. Как это исправить?

```js
gulp.task('pug',function () {
    return gulp.src('app/blocks/**/*.pug')
        .pipe(pug({pretty: true}))//{pretty: true} читаемость и каскадность кода
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите плагин [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename),подключите плагин в gulpfile.js:

```js
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
```

, и измените код таска например так:

```js
    gulp.task('pug',function () {
        return gulp.src('app/blocks/**/*.pug')
            .pipe(pug({pretty: true}))//{pretty: true} читаемость и каскадность кода
            .pipe(rename({
            dirname: ""
}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
    });
```

Будет складывать файлы в папку app без папок в которых находились pug файлы.